# Python Suds error "ns (None) not mapped"

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I`m not familiar with`WSDL`and`XSD`, my problem with Suds is the following:
According to Sud`s documentation I am trying to create a client object -

```
url = "http://192.168.1.21/crs/RateService.svc?singleWsdl"
client = Client(url)
```

but after

```
print client
```

I had an issue:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

ns (None) not mapped
```

in debug log I found that (in the end of file):

```
DEBUG:suds.xsd.query:TypeQuery:0x7f7528743050, found builtin (dateTime)
ERROR:suds.servicedefinition:ns (None) not mapped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 245, in __unicode__
    return self.description()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 236, in description
    s.append(self.xlate(t[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 193, in xlate
    prefix = self.getprefix(ns[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/servicedefinition.py", line 176, in getprefix
    raise Exception('ns (%s) not mapped'  % u)
Exception: ns (None) not mapped
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all I'd suggest using a newer version of `suds` in the shape of the `suds-jurko` fork.

Comment: Ready, currently using Suds version - Suds-jurko 0.6, but nothing changes. The same error.

Comment: Then I'm afraid we're going to have to see the WSDL.

Comment: Unfortunately, I hadn`t right for posting such materials (like a WSDL, XML) because this are corporative property.

Answer (score 0):

This time I successfully created some objects (not all needed) by suds `client.factory.create({namespace}SomeElement)` .
It seems there are incorrect definitions in WSDL, because print of client object produce same error and using suds Import and ImportDoctor gives same result.